# SELinux permissions for a socket and PID

Tags: centos7, selinux

I'm looking at getting [rmilter](https://github.com/vstakhov/rmilter) installed on a CentOS 7 box. I'm trying to work out which SELinux labels/permissions I need for the daemon to bind/write to the following

`pidfile = /run/rmilter/rmilter.pid;
bind_socket = unix:/run/rmilter/rmilter.sock;`

Here's how redis and rmilter compare, for example (under /run) 

`drwxr-xr-x. redis redis system_u:object_r:redis_var_run_t:s0 redis
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  unconfined_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 rmilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already checked your auditlog (/var/log/audit/audit.log)!

you can try to run audit2allow provided with policycoreutils-python package (you can install it with yum), to get more information about the policy you need to configure! This tool can even help you to generate a policy file you can after load with semodule!

check the man page but
audit2allow -w: will help you to understand why your application doesn't work with the current policy

audit2allow -M policy_name : will help you to generate a policy

and then semodule -i policy_name.pp: will install the generated policy (don't forget to check the newly created rules before applying)

Eg: Some command  I have done to configure passenger module with apache and selinux:

`grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log|audit2allow -w
grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log|audit2allow -M passenger
semodule -i passenger.pp`

Cheer,
Julian